# htmlentities and htmlspecialchars refuse to process string

Tags: php, mysql, row, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

Since the last update to **PHP5 5.4.0-3** on my Debian box I noticed that some pages have empty fields where text from the MySQL database should be.

I played around a bit and found the problem.

```php
<?php
$scselect = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `forum_threads` WHERE `forum` = '1' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC") or exit((mysql_error()));
    while ($scrow=mysql_fetch_array($scselect))
    {
        var_dump($scrow['name']);
        var_dump(htmlentities($scrow['name']));
    }
?>
```

strangely this is whats printed:

```php
string(18) "php hu3: the Forum"
string(0) ""
string(18) "php hu2 score-rule"
string(0) ""
string(6) "php hu"
string(0) ""
string(15) "HU 8: Binarycnt"
string(0) ""
```

but if I use htmlentities with hardcoded content -> htmlentities("test"); it works like charm.
Also if I do this:

```php
var_dump("a".$scrow['name']);
```

it also says

```php
string(0) ""
```

But it gets stranger. If I use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars with any other variable from the database it works just perfectly.

```php
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($scrow['ID'])); // prints for example string(2) "87"
```

what can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
htmlentities($scrow['name'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: this seems to work.. but its killing my umlauts.. and why was this no issue before the update?

Comment: @Christian What if you use `ISO-8859-1` or `cp1252`, instead of `UTF-8`?

Comment: that works! thanks! is there any way to tell php that it should always use ISO-8859-1 without me having to add that to every htmlentities call?

Answer (score 2):

Recommended approach is to hard code the character set each time you use htmlentities.

This is a feature of the htmlentities call, and not affected by the default character set.
[migration54](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.other.php)

Answer (score 1):

the cause of this can be another encoding returned from the database (like UTF8)

so play a little around with `utf8_encode($string)` or `utf8_decode($string)`

another approach would be playing around with the encoding argument of htmlentities:

https://www.php.net/htmlentities

Comment: its strange though that it worked a day ago. Didn't change the code nor the database